# constants in react native

Tags: react-native, constants

how can I create a constant in react native? I have considered putting it in state but this allows the value to be changed. Here is my code:

```
export default class test extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {answer:42}   // I'd like answer to be a constant
  }
}
```

I normal java script I would use `const answer = 42` however this doesn't work:

```
this.state = {const answer:42}
```

How can this be done? Thanks

PS:

I am looking for something similar to `#define` in C

Comment: Have you looked into AsyncStorage? It accepts a string value and can only be changed by calling AsyncStorage.setItem().https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: I was thinking something more in line with C's #define directive however this will work fine, thanks for this

Comment: That's not a valid object, so it simply won't work.  I would reference the value from a stored enum/type file if using TypeScript and or just a const file declared globally and imported into your file.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, yes I realize what I've done above doesn't work, hence the question

Comment: How about a .env file with your constants, and reference them by calling `process.env.YOUR_KEY`?

Comment: sure, thats a good idea, I'll look into that

Comment: If you need a constant, definitely don't put into the state. State should only be used for variables you want to change throughout the lifetime of that component. Less state should always be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a .env file with your constants, and reference them by calling `process.env.YOUR_KEY`

You will likely need to install this package to extract the values from your .env file: [dotenv packege on Github](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)